# MySQL query with typeorm

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, typeorm

I'm new to mysql and trying to make my problem solved. Have tried and now, let me ask you.

I am using typeorm, mysql and express.

Business logic is:

There will be cars with licenseNo and driver phone number. They will arrive car-gates and admin from that car-gates will record which cars has been arrived to their car-gates.

And the requirement is:
Let say car1 reached to gate1 (reaching pattern will be non-sequential) and admin from gate1 record it in database in below table.
After that, in the arriving-list UI of that admin of gate1, there must NOT be that car1 because car1 has reached to that gate1.

But, for other gates (gate2), in the arriving-list UI of gate2, car1 should be displayed because car1 has not arrived to gate2 yet.
Same for other gates (gate3, gate4 and so on), they should be able to see car1 in the UI as well.

Now after car1 is reached to gate1 and admin gate1 has recorded in db, gate 2 can see that now. After car1 reached to gate2 and admin gate2 recorded, gate2 can’t see that car1 now. Gate1 admin cannot also see car 1 as it has reached but for gate3, gate4 and so on will see car 1 until one of those gate marks their own gate last-gate. If one of gates marks themselves as last gate for car1, other gates can not see gate1 at all. All of that should be within a day.

(In the recording screen of each gate, there is a checkbox of isLastGate. Admin from a particular gate can check that checkbox and meaning is that car will not be coming to next gates. So, other new gates should not be seen it in their arriving-list ui.)

Below is my ProcessingGates entity.  
licensePlate: string,
driverPhone: string,
isLastGate: boolean,
gateId: string,
  
And api request will pass gateId.

I tried these queries:

```
const values = await ProcessingGatesRepository.createQueryBuilder()
      .select('ar.licenseNo, MAX(ar.createdAt) AS latestTimestamp')
      .from(ProcessingGate, 'ar')
      .where('ar.gateId != :gateId', { gateId })
      .andWhere(
        'NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM processing_gate ar2 WHERE ar2.licenseNo = ar.licenseNo AND ar2.gateId = :gateId)'
      )
      .groupBy('ar.licenseNo')
      .getRawMany();

    console.log(values);
```

```
const now = new Date();
    const startOfToday = new Date(now);
    startOfToday.setHours(6, 0, 0, 0);

    const whereClauses: FindOptionsWhere<ProcessingGate> = {};
    if (!!searchText) {
      whereClauses['licenseNo'] = ILike(`%${searchText}%`);
    }
    whereClauses['gateId'] = Not(Equal(gateId));
    whereClauses['isLastGate'] = Equal(false);
    whereClauses['createdAt'] = MoreThanOrEqual(startOfToday);
    const options: FindManyOptions<ProcessingGate> = {
      where: whereClauses,
      relations: ['gate'],
      order: { createdAt: 'DESC' },
    };
    if (limit != undefined && offset != undefined) {
      options['skip'] = offset;
      options['take'] = limit;
    }
    return await ProcessingGateRepository.findAndCount(options);
```

Comment: And what's the question? You have not asked any in your post...

Comment: I want to get the list of different cars that have arrived at other gates if they are not marked as last gate.

for example, car1 has arrived to gate1 and gate1 admin recorded it in db. 
and I stored in processing_gates table (gateId, carId and isLastTerminal = false).

After that, as gate1 admin, i should not see that car1. but for admin gate2, he should see that car1. @Shadow

Comment: And what's wrong with your current code? Please also provide sample data, expected results and the results your current code produces!